# Use multiple EXEC statements depending on a SELECT result

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, exec

I have an (Oracle SQL) query that searches for problems: (simplified)

```
select a.date, (a.counter1 + c.counter) / (c.counter1 - a.counter1) percentdiferent
  --daily table is agregated to ocupy less space and be faster when searching for the total counters for a day
  from dailytable a
  join (
    --the nonaggregated table has values for each minute
    select trunc(b.date) date, sum(counter1) counter1 
      from minutetable b
      where trunc(b.datea) = a.date
      group by trunc(b.date)
  ) c
  on c.date = a.date and c.counter1 <> a.counter1
  where percentdiferent > 5
```

To correct these problems I need to execute a procedure:

```
exec aggregate(tablename, date)
```

The procedures change often and I have more than one table. Is there a way to do something like

```
with checktables as (
  --above code
)

select date
  from checktables
  group by date

if result > 0
  for each result
    exec aggregate(tablename,date) 

show results
```

?

Comment: Is it okay to use PL/SQL or shell script?

Comment: only pl/sql :(, we here dont have complete access to the machines :(

Answer (score 0):

within a query you are allowed to use functions but you are not allowed to use stored procedures.
if you have to call a stored procedure you should use a cursor and loop through your results [PL/SQL Cursors on Oracle.com](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html)

```
BEGIN
   FOR c IN (SELECT * FROM tablename) 
   LOOP
       your_procedure(c.columnname, c.othercolumnname);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
    l_check_state NUMBER;

    /* example procedures */
    PROCEDURE work_with_one
    AS
    BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Procedure one');
    END work_with_one;

    PROCEDURE work_with_two
    AS
    BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Procedure two');
    END work_with_two;

    PROCEDURE work_with_three
    AS
    BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Procedure three');
    END work_with_three;
BEGIN
    /* check query */
    WITH checktables AS
    (
        SELECT  ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 3)) AS state
        FROM    dual
    )
    SELECT  state
    INTO    l_check_state
    FROM    checktables;

    /* based on the query result run proper procedure */
    IF l_check_state = 1 THEN
        /* execute proc 1 */
        work_with_one();
    ELSIF l_check_state = 2 THEN
        /* execute proc 2 */
        work_with_two();
    ELSIF l_check_state = 3 THEN
        /* execute proc 3 */
        work_with_three();
    ELSE
        /* no evaluation */
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error');
    END IF;
END;
```

Because of a random number (DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) when you run it several times you will see different results. It is used to simulated check query behaviour.

```
Procedure two
Procedure one
Procedure two
Procedure one
```